# VueJS displaying server errors laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to use vue js in laravel to display errors. I'm following a tutorial which can be seen here: https://www.laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/19

Here is a snipet of the code which is being used to get errors. When the error class has no values in the object the code errors. The if statement should prevent any values being returned if errors has no values however despite this the code still errors.

Here is the error message: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
get(field) {
  if (this.errors[field]) { //line that's causing the problem 
        return this.errors[field][0];
    }
}
```

Here is the entire vue.js file

```
console.log('running');

window.Vue = Vue;

class Errors {

constructor() {
    this.errors = {};
}

get(field) {
    if (this.errors[field]) {
        return this.errors[field][0];
    }
}

record(errors) {
    this.errors = errors;
}
}

var venue = new Vue({
el: '#venueVue',

data: {
   errors: new Errors(),
   name: '',

},

methods: {
    onSubmit() {
       axios.post('/venue/', {
           name: this.name,

       })
           .then(response => alert('success'))
           .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors));
    }
}
});
```

and here is the html

```
 <span class="alert alert-danger" v-text="errors.get('name')"></span>
```

Comment: What is the value of `this.errors`?

Comment: this.errors is an object that gets populated with an array when validation errors happen from a server request

Comment: Yes I gathered that but it doesn't answer the question. What is the value of it?

Comment: I've fixed it by making sure that this.errors never gets undefined. Thanks for you time anyway.

Comment: Ok, that's where I was leading to. It was the only viable way to raise that error.

Comment: Yeah bad communication from me, thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: That's what we're here for, no problem and glad it's sorted.